# Odata query $filter alternative

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, odata

Are there any alternatives to $filter in OData query options ?

Below is my $filter code to select certain data from SharePoint. But due to certain problems with the server, I was unable to execute the query. Are there any alternatives such as $select statement or whichever that does the same function as below ?

```
ListData?$filter=ContentType eq 'Item'&$top=100
```

Answer (score 0):

`$filter` is the only option for filtering data, there is no other way to get only `ListData` where the `ContentType` is `Item`. Alternatively, (and much less performantly), if you really can't do `$filter` but need to get the data, you could just get back all of the data and do the filtering on the client.